# Sometimes android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID on API 21

Tags: android, string, exception

I have strange problem.
In my App on crash sended log with exception. Sometimes I get strange error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050095
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1334)
```

Other parts of stack trace may be different. String ID maybe different too.

It occurs only on API 21 Android 5.0 or 5.0.1. 
And then, not always.

In other API and Android versions - problem don't occurs.

I have /res/values/strings.xml with needed data.

What could be the problem?
Is it possible that this is a problem specific firmware?

Or maybe, apk was damaged after installation?

Because, as I understand it, whether the problem is the code, it would be all time.

Comment: Do you have any harcoded ID like, miView.setId(200) ?

Comment: No. Any ids written as R.string.thank_you

Comment: can you post your code which is causing this?

Comment: For example: `Toast.makeText(Bulldog.instance, R.string.thank_you, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` in other times: `.setTitle(R.string.select_application)` - this called on AlertDialog$Builder. Another occurs on .setMessage on AlertDialog$Builder.

Comment: could be a lot of things. the most obvious would be a missing default translation for a given string.

Comment: default translation for a given string is present. Perhaps the problem is that I use a context of activity for which it was called Destroy? But other versions of android it is no problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I found the problem was due to the fact that the resources used for the activity have destroyed.